# React - get data with axios

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, openweathermap, react-class-based-component

In my **react** app that is based on class components, My response **API** got from open weather fixes after several **lags**.
this is my state

```
class Weather extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      weatherData: undefined,
      weatherDescription: undefined,
    };
  }
```

My thinking was that when my **componentDidMount**,
weather API getting from [openWeather](https://openweathermap.org/current) and set it in state

```
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(
        `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=someCityId&units=metric&appid=myApiKey`
      )
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.request.status === 200) {
            this.setState({
              weatherData: response.data.main.temp,
              weatherDescription: response.data.weather[0].description,
              weatherTextDisplay: this.state.airConditionsText.filter((item)=>{
                return item["id"] === response.data.weather[0].id
              })
            });
        }else{throw Error('No internet')}
      })
      .catch(error => Error.message)
```

and I want to update data when the city is changing, in **componentDidUpdate** the data get again from the [openWeather](https://openweathermap.org/current)

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    axios
      .get(
        `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=someCityId&units=metric&appid=myApiKey`
      )
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.request.status === 200) {
            this.setState({
              weatherData: response.data.main.temp,
              weatherDescription: response.data.weather[0].description,
              weatherTextDisplay: this.state.airConditionsText.filter((item)=>{
                return item["id"] === response.data.weather[0].id
              })
            });
        }else{throw Error('No internet')}
      })
      .catch(error => Error.message)

  }
```

But the problem is that when my response receives, it faces a lag that causes data jumps several times to previous data and new data until it fixes

Comment: I at least want to display loading text until my response completely get

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I do not completely understand  the question, but this 'lags' because the action of fetching something from an external source is async and needs time to complete.

As for the second 'part' of displaying the loading text you have to set a variable (preferably in state which indicates the loading state of this component)

eg.

```js
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       loading: false,
       airConditionsText: null,
       // Other stuff you have in state
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.setState({loading: true}) // Start of loading
    axios
      .get(
        `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=${this.state.inputId}&units=metric&appid=myApiKey`
      )
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.request.status === 200) {
            this.setState({
              weatherData: response.data.main.temp,
              weatherDescription: response.data.weather[0].description,
              weatherTextDisplay: this.state.airConditionsText.filter((item)=>{
                return item["id"] === response.data.weather[0].id
              })
            });
        }else{throw Error('No internet')}
      })
      .catch(error => Error.message)
      .finally(() => this.setState({loading: false})) // End of loading
```

`.finally` is being trigger once the async operation (fetching the data from weatherAPI) finishes with either error or success which is the time to stop loading.

Then you can use `this.state.loading` in component render to show loading text
eg.

```
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          {this.state.loading 
            ? <div> Loading... </div> 
            : <div>{this.state.airConditionsText}</div> // other stuff you want to display
          } 
        </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: My main problem is that lag and it causes my data loads after several jumps,  you are right, I try to get a response from [openWeather](https://openweathermap.org/) to show the weather temperature on my page, But it seems to need time to complete, so **how can I handle that lag**?

Comment: I wrote in my bottom example.. Based on the loading state you can display your own loading animation instead of `<div>loading...</div>`